# FontSize set in Style does not match FontSize in Blend

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, font-size

I have a label in a grid and I apply a style to it from a resource dictionary. The style changes, among other things, the FontSize property of the label to 14.

```
    <Style x:Key="lblForm" TargetType= "{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,6,0"/>
</Style>
```

I apply the style to the label in the following manner:

```
<Label x:Name="lblFirstName" Content="First name:" Style="{StaticResource lblForm}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

When I inspect the same label element in the Blend designer, the FontSize property is **not** the same as that set in the style. For example, when the FontSize property is set to 14 in the style, the designer says the FontSize is 10.5. If I increase the FontSize property in the style it also increases when I view it in the designer, but it is never the same. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `FontSize` in different ways. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize.aspx):

> `<object FontSize ="qualifiedDouble"/>`
>
> qualifiedDouble A double value as previously described that is
> followed by one of these unit declaration strings: px, in, cm, pt.
>
> px (default) is device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit)
>
> in is inches; 1in==96px
>
> cm is centimeters; 1cm==(96/2.54) px
>
> pt is points; 1pt==(96/72) px

In your style when don't set it explicitly it defaults to **px**.
But Blend calculates with **pt** [image]

That's why the two values are different.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of that.